# UIButton in Modal View over UIToolBar Over UITabBar Touch Not Detected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, touch, uibarbuttonitem

I have a toolbar at the bottom of my view. There is a UIBarButton called Scan that needs to detect when someone is holding their finger down and when they lifted up.

Because UIBarButton inherits from UIControl I wasn't able to detect this. As a workaround I created a UIButton that is invisible and placed it on top of my toolbar and simply detect touches from it instead of the UIBarButton.

This works fine until I present the view as a Modal View (which hides the UITabBar) if I touch where the toolbar would be I cannot detect it. If I touch above the toolbar it works fine.

Here is a screenshot. (the invisible button has been colored red and stretched to be tall for testing)

[image: working state]

In the screenshot below if you touch where the toolbar is nothing happens. but above it where it is red it works perfectly.

[image]

Here is some of my code.

```
    - (IBAction) scanTouchUp:(id)sender {
    [linea barcodeStopScan:nil];  
}

- (IBAction) scanTouchDown:(id)sender {
    [linea barcodeStartScan:nil];   
}
```

Those methods are attached to the "Touch Down" and "Touch Up Inside/Outside" respectively.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So the part in red is where you still want to detect touches in Modal View? And only the red part?

Comment: Yes, underneath the red box is a uibarbutton item that says "Scan". When you hold down on the red part it activates a barcode scanner peripheral.

Answer (score 1):

If the UIButton goes over the edge of its parent view, or covers part of a different descendant view then it may be the case that hit testing isn't working for the button. (i.e. the button is over the top of the bar at the bottom).

You can resolve these issues by ensuring that button is hit test. You may be able to do this by overriding the the `hitTest:withEvent:` method on the view that contains the button. This may look something like this:

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UIView *result = [redButton hitTest:[redButton convertPoint:point fromView:self] withEvent:event];
  if (result)
    return result;

  return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

This will only work if the view that you're adding this change to is hit test before another view that contains the given point.

Comment: Seconded, it's almost assuredly hit-testing. Views drawn outside their superviews bounds are visible but not tappable. Setting `clipsToBounds` to `YES` on your views will help in debugging this sort of issue.

Comment: I'm getting "No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'hitTest:withEven:' for the "return [super hitTest:point with Event:event];

Comment: Yes, you would need to subclass the view that you are adding the button to as a subview.

Comment: I subclassed it. I created an IBOutlet. Then in my nib I changed the UIView to my subclass and attached the button as a new reference outlet. It didn't make a difference :(

Comment: I just noticed that if I touch down, then move my finger outside the bounds of the button and keep it down it registers as a touch down.

Comment: I've written a blog post on hit testing and how iOS finds which view will respond [here](http://www.twistedape.me.uk/blog/blog/2013/10/05/ios-what-happens-when-i-touch-the-screen/) I hope this is useful.

Comment: @JamesSnook I tried your suggestion and the hitTest doesn't work but pointInside is returning the correct result.

Comment: @JamesSnook K Scratch my previous question. I fixed my code and the button registers as a result in both cases. (hitTest and pointInside) but the button behavior is still doing the same thing.

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm reaching the end of my ability to remotely debug this problem! Have you got a gestureRecognizer attached to a view that may be stealing the touches (they interfere with the responder chain)? Other than that there's the obvious things to double check. You're target and action are correct? They're firing on UIControlEventTouchUpInside? You're button `isEnabled`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an invisible button over the toolbar manually, try to create a `UIBarButton` instance with

`- (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView`

and add it to the toolbar as every other item.

This custom view (passed to the method mentioned above) would be a "scan" button. You can then handle it just as you want, without resorting to some invisible controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I think you need to add your toolbar to the subview first. Then only you add your invisible button to the subview. Make sure both of them have the same superview.